# I want to test performance with Jmeter

Tags: php, jmeter

I am new in `Jmeter` and I want to test the performance of my site.

It is coded with PHP, So, I want to pass values to the login page and later on the next page execute some actions like select some options in the second page.

That is possible?.

Please could you provide how to do it?. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter can be used to run your recorded performance tests. I would suggest you two ways to record you scripts:

1. You could use Jmeter recorder to record you test execution flow. Refer below link to set up:
   https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html
2. You can register on Blazemeter -> Add Blazemeter Chrome extension to Google chrome -> It will appear as below

[image]

Click on the Blazemeter icon

[image]

Click on the red circle to start recording your test

[image]

After successfully recording your flow -> Click on Stop button and Save the file as JMX file (this JMX file will be used in Jmeter)

Open Jmeter and upload the script(JMX file) created above and run the test using Jmeter

**Note: For passing values you can use HTTP Header Manager in Jmeter, you can also add HTTP Header manager to individual threads/APIs or at the Thread Group level.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the same [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) as the real browser does in order to mimic the end-user's behaviour. The main test element you should be looking for is [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

In addition you will need other elements like [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to handle cookies, [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) for implementing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic data, etc.

I would suggest the following steps:

1. Record your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Get familiarized with [Building a Web Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) and [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html) articles to learn what generated test elements are doing
3. Perform parameterization and correlation of the test, check [How to use JMeter for Login Authentication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication-) for example actions you would need to take
4. Verify that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing using 1-2 virtual users and loops and inspecting requests/responses details in [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)
5. Once you're happy with your test you can run as many virtual users you want to simulate in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and analyze the results using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)